# User's profiles as actors with akka.cluster. Routing and creating

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka.net

I want to use Akka.Cluster for simple user profile service. There will be few instances of http-api services witch will send messages for some backend instances with userprofile persistent actors(Profile Actor).
Every http-api service can send message for same Profile Actor, so I should use Consistent Hashing Group router. But if I'll use group router, I should for every Profile Actor add route to group router, as I know, it's impossible. I can't use pool router, because every instance of http-api with pool router, will create his own Profile Actor for one user. How can I implement user's profile with akka.cluster? Maybe it's exist some patterns for same situations?

Comment: http://blog.geist.no/an-actor-model-example-with-akka-net/

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Akka Cluster Sharding will be useful. 
See at [Cluster Sharding](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0-RC1/scala/cluster-sharding.html)

Solution 2: [Custom routing](https://github.com/afiskon/akka-cluster-router-example). This solution is simple to move to Akka.NET.

Comment: Thank you, but first solution not useful because it will one cluster shard with few nodes. About Custom routing is useful, but I don't like this solution because routers are specific actors with functionality of fast forwarding,simple actors are not so fast.

Comment: In first solution you can implement shardId() method in ShardRegion.MessageExtractor interface (valid for Java). This method is used to determine the number of shard.

Comment: Oh, I understand. It' cool but cluster sharding not yet exist in Akka.net